# left join two tables such that two columns of table 2 does not exist in table1

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables table1(userid,regid) and table2(userid,hostuserid,status) where either userid or hostuserid equals myuserid(already contained in a variable $userid).I want to find all rows in table1 such that table1.userid!=table2.userid AND table1.userid!=table2.userid.

```
table1
--------
userid regid
 1     gbjnknnk
 2     bvgcghb
 3     bjbnjb

 table2
 -------
 userid hostuserid 
  1       5
  5       2

  $userid=5
```

query should return only one row=> 3 bjbnjb
how to implement the same.
what i had tried

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE (table1.userid!=table2.userid AND 
table2.hostuserid=$userid) AND (table1.userid!=table2.hostuserid AND 
table2.userid=$userid)
```

Comment: if you want things that do not match, then you're not looking for a join ... I am guessing you want a subquery using `where table1.userid not in(select userid from table2) and table1.userid not in (select hostuserid from table2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a not in  on a subselect with union

```
select userid 
from table1 
where user1 not in ( 
      select userid 
      from table2 
      union 
      select 
      hostuserid from table2
)
```

Comment: it did it already.but due to my low reputation you will not get any points.sorry bro

Comment: le bhai jee le apni zindagi.